# ¿Como enviar un email en Django desde diferentes direcciones de correo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Tengo un sitio en el cual una de sus funcionalidades es contener una tabla de proveedores y otra tabla de clientes, en donde cada cliente y proveedor cuenta con un campo que contiene su e-mail. Lo que pretendo realizar es que el usuario pueda enviar un e-mail al cliente o proveedor que seleccione a través del servidor de SMTP de Gmail. El incoveniente es que el usuario cuenta con multiples direcciones de correo y por lo que tengo comprendido el archivo settings.py permite definir las variables de entorno que configuran la conexion al servidor SMTP de Gmail pero luego no permite modificalarlas en tiempo de ejución, por lo que esto me impide utilizar multiples direcciones de correo pertenecientes al usuario.

> Archivo settings.py:

```
EMAL_BACKEND="django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST="smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True 
EMAIL_PORT="587"
EMAIL_HOST_USER="usuario@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD="contraseñaUsuario"
```